# Func<T>() vs Func<T>.Invoke()

Tags: c#, invoke, func

I'm curious about the differences between calling a `Func<T>` directly vs. using `Invoke()` on it.  Is there a difference? Is the first syntactical sugar and calls `Invoke()` underneath anyway?

```cs
public T DoWork<T>(Func<T> method)
{
    return (T)method.Invoke();
}
```

vs.

```cs
public T DoWork<T>(Func<T> method)
{
    return (T)method();
}
```

Or am I on the wrong track entirely?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/f629c34d-6523-433a-90b3-bb5d445c5587

Answer (score 161, accepted):

There's no difference at all. The second is just a shorthand for `Invoke`, provided by the compiler. They compile to the same IL.

Comment: Leaving the Invoke() method off is resulting in the compiler error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<T>' to 'T' ". I'm compiling against .NET 4.

Comment: @Mike: That would happen if you'd missed the *brackets* off as well - i.e. tried to return `(T)method` rather than `(T)method()`.

Comment: @JonSkeet So is this guy wrong here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f629c34d-6523-433a-90b3-bb5d445c5587/differences-between-delegate-invoke-and-call-a-method-directly?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: @superlogical: There are two problems here. Firstly, the question there is about the difference between calling a method directly and calling it via a delegate. That's not the same as the difference between `foo()` and `foo.Invoke()` where `foo` is a variable of a delegate type. The other problem is that the *answer* seems to be talking about `Control.Invoke`, which isn't the same as calling `Invoke` on a delegate.

Comment: Has the OP edited his original post after reading Jon Skeet's comment? I can't  track down what jon is referring to.

Comment: @xDisruptor: There are two pieces of code, and the OP is asking whether they're equivalent. My response is that they compile to the same IL. I'm not sure what's confusing you.

Comment: Upon reading your comment again I realized you were commenting on the link provided by superlogical - not the original post. For someone that is reading quickly through the comments it's not so clear what it is you are commenting on: "The answer seems to be talking about Control.Invoke etc)." <- I thought you where referring to the very answer you provided here, but you are referring to the other answer provided in social.msdn

Comment: Which syntax do you prefer and why? I personally think that using `Invoke()` does not add anything in terms of readability or maintainability so I'd rather use the syntax without it.

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: If it's the result of a method call, I generally like `Invoke`, as `GetAction()()` looks weird, but `GetAction().Invoke()` looks okay. But I don't mind either way, for the most part.

Answer (score 30):

Invoke works well with new C# 6 null propagation operator, now you can do

```
T result = method?.Invoke();
```

instead of

```
T result = method != null ? method() : null;
```

Comment: Can you illustrate a scenario where this is useful? The textbook case is raising events.

Comment: For example you can have an optional Func parameter that if no value is assigned, is the default(Func) which is null and is ignored.

Comment: It's the common case for events and other multi-cast delegates - they are usually initialized with null and gain non-null value after calling `+=`. So if you are going to fire an event and don't know if there are any subscriptions, the concise solution is to call `?.Invoke(...)`.