# Get method-reference without specifying all input argument types

Tags: c#, generics, moq

I want to quickly mock some method calls with Moq. I do have some long-winded method signatures with very long argument-type names and, lazy as I am, don't want to type out `It.IsAny<>()` for all of them when the method is setup to fail anyway, *regardless of the amount of input-arguments*.
More specifically, I came up with this extension-method, but `T1` (the first argument) is not bound in the example call:

```
public static void SetResult<T,T1,TResult>(this Mock<T> mock, Func<T, Func<T1, TResult>> method, TResult result, Func<T1> filterT1 = null) 
   where T : class
{
    if(filterT1 == null) 
    { 
       filterT1 = It.IsAny<T1>; 
    }
    mock.Setup(m => method.Invoke(m).Invoke(filterT1.Invoke()))
        .Returns(result);
}

// I want to use this like the following
Mock<Foo> mock = /* ... */;
mock.SetResult(foo => foo.bar, "Some return value");                   // Doesn't work
mock.SetResult<Foo, int, string>(foo => foo.bar, "Some return value"); // Works
mock.SetResult(foo => foo.bar, "Some return value", () => 42);         // Works too
```

Now my IDE, rightfully, complains that it has no idea what `T1` is, because the type is nowhere explicitly used in the method-signature.

**How can I change the `SetResult`-Method that I can still just reference the method on `Foo` in a simple, quick way, but without specifying all Type-Parameters?**

Some more reliefs/constraints:

- You may use reflection to gather information about the method (for example its input-parameters).
- The call to `SetResult` should be as simple as possible, ideally only referencing the method to setup and the return-value.
- `SetResult` must be expandable to any number of input-types (that is, `bar` in the above example-call might also take a `T2`, `T3`, ...)

  - I'm aware that this requires multiple `SetResult`-Definitions.
- Ideally I want to use optional arguments for the filters, which fall back from `null` to `It.IsAny` (as in the code-example). I *could* live without these filters and use `It.IsAny` for all arguments.

---

Some tripwires specific to my code-sample (ignore for the general question):

Moq allows to mock function calls and inspect the input-parameters. These are some normal setups, which my above `SetResult`-Method is supposed to boil down to (the last one with `IsAny`).

```
// "Normal" setups
mock.Setup(m => m.bar(42)).Returns("Some value")                     // Only allow input 42
mock.Setup(m => m.bar(It.Is(i => i % 2 == 0))).Returns("Some value") // Only allow even inputs
mock.Setup(m => m.bar(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns("Some value")        // Allow any int-input
```

`Setup` expects an `Expression<Func<TObject,TResult>>` (note the missing type-definitions for the `bar`-input-types) and inspects that to mock the call. Any `It.*`-calls can only be made in this expression (see [this question and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46973555/3892515) of why I use `*.invoke()`).

The endresult will not only be methods that set results, but also exceptions, sequences, ...
But I can figure that out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

This might need a little refinement, but it seems to get somewhere close to what you're talking about. The only difference is that it currently takes a `MethodInfo` rather than a `Func` to get the method it should be mocking.

It iterates over all the parameters and uses `System.Linq.Expression` to create an `IsAny` expression for each parameter.

```
public static class MoqExtension
{
    public static void SetResult<T, TResult>(this Mock<T> mock, MethodInfo methodInfo, TResult result)
        where T : class
    {
        var expressions = new List<Expression>();
        // Create IsAny for each parameter
        foreach (var parameter in methodInfo.GetParameters())
        {
            var pType = parameter.ParameterType;

            var isAnyMethod = typeof(It).GetMethods((BindingFlags)(-1))
                .Where(x => x.Name == "IsAny")
                .First();

            var genericIsAnyMethod = isAnyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(pType);

            var isAnyExp = Expression.Call(genericIsAnyMethod);
            expressions.Add(isAnyExp);
        }

        // Create method call
        var argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var callExp = Expression.Call(argParam, methodInfo, expressions.ToArray());
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(callExp, argParam);

        // invoke setup method
        var mockType = mock.GetType();
        var setupMethod = mockType.GetMethods()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Setup" && x.IsGenericMethod)
            .First();
        var genericMethod = setupMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TResult));

        var res = genericMethod.Invoke(mock, new object[] { lambda }) as ISetup<T, TResult>;

        res.Returns(result);
    }
}
```

usage example:

```
    [Fact]
    public void MoqTestDynamic2()
    {
        var m = new Mock<ITestInterface>();

        m.SetResult(typeof(ITestInterface).GetMethod("GetAnotherInt"), 168);

        Assert.Equal(168, m.Object.GetAnotherInt("s", 1, 3));
        Assert.Equal(168, m.Object.GetAnotherInt("p", 1, 35));
        Assert.Equal(168, m.Object.GetAnotherInt(null, 1, 3));
    }

    public interface ITestInterface
    {
        int GetInt(string s);

        int GetAnotherInt(string s, int i, long l);
    }
```

There must be a better way to

1. Express the method we want to mock, rather than passing a MethodInfo
2. Pass in any non defailt filters we may want to