# Asp.Net Core 2.x middleware syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware

I encountered several ways of writing simple middleware directly in Startup.Configure() method:

```
// Syntax 1.
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    return next();
});

// Syntax 2.
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    await next();
});

// Syntax 3.
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    await next.Invoke();
});

// Syntax 4.
app.Use(next =>
{
    return ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        return next(ctx);
    };
});
```

Are they all the same?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c) might be worth a look for 1 vs 2

Answer (score 7):

**Syntax 1 and Syntax 2 are functionally different.** Syntax 1 does not wait for `next()` to finish its `Task`. Syntax 1 is passing a normal lambda function to `Use` and is returning the `Task` without waiting for it to complete. Syntax 2 is passing an `async` lambda function and is `awaiting` the `Task` before returning. The `await` keyword tells the app to pause execution until the `next()` task is complete. In the code from your example, that might not lead to a functional difference, but there are times when waiting for a `Task` to complete can make a difference.

**Syntax 2 and Syntax 3 are syntactically different and functionally identical.** Syntax 2 is just a user-friendly versions of Syntax 3. See [Func<T>() vs Func<T>.Invoke()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16309286/1108891)

**Syntax 1 and Syntax 4 are syntactically different and functionally identical.** Syntax 1 is just a user-friendly wrapper around Syntax 4. See [UseExtension.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/043f8fda61931ee23416bd68865f3623f3ce2ac2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/UseExtensions.cs#L21-L32)

```
// syntax 1,2,3 use this 
public static IApplicationBuilder Use(
    this IApplicationBuilder app, 
    Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task> middleware)
{
    // which calls into syntax4
    return app.Use(next =>
    {
        return context =>
        {
            Func<Task> simpleNext = () => next(context);
            return middleware(context, simpleNext);
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Syntax 4 is using `Use` method of `IApplicationBuilder`

```
IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)
```

Syntax 1, 2 and 3 are using an extension method for `IApplicationBuilder` which is a wrapper of previous method in Syntax 4. Here's the implimentation

```
public static IApplicationBuilder Use(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<HttpContext, Func<Task>, Task> middleware)
{
    return app.Use(next =>
    {
        return context =>
        {
            Func<Task> simpleNext = () => next(context);
            return middleware(context, simpleNext);
        };
    });
}
```

For Syntax 2 and 3, there is no difference between `next.Invoke()` and `next()`. They both compile to the same method.