# Differences in the way of writing lambdas in VB

Tags: vb.net

So I've been reading up on lambdas in VB recently and am a bit confused tbh. I've got the code running properly, but want a better understanding. My main question is the use of the Invoke() method and the way of declaring a lambda.

One method I've seen is this:

```
Dim increment2 = Function(x)
                     Return x + 2
                 End Function
```

and the other:

```
Dim func1 As Func(Of Integer, Integer) =
                    Function(value As Integer)
                            Return value + 1
                     End Function
```

My question is, what's the difference? And what role does the Invoke() method play. I've seen to ways of calling lambdas, one like func1(4) and the other is func1.Invoke(4).

I should mention, that regardless of what change I make the output remains the same (5), leading me believe the change is something not very noticeable. And I'm curious as to what it is.

Comment: The first one will not compile with `Option Strict On`, the second one will. Not to be confused with [generic type inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-procedures#type-inference). As for `Invoke()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16309286/11683.

Comment: What's the recommended way? The first example is from the Docs, the second is from another site.

Comment: I recommend turning `Option String On`, `Option Explicit On` and `Option Infer On` in the VS settings globally for all projects, and fix any code that stops compiling. You can dismiss that recommendation.

Comment: I see. In short, I should follow the second example?

Comment: I prefer using type inference when possible. That would be `Dim increment2 = Function(x As Integer)
                     Return x + 2
                 End Function`

Comment: Thanks. You've helped quite a bit. I'll leave this open for a while if someone else has anything useful to add. I'll close this in 24 hours.

Comment: @StormClaw If there's anything relevant here don't close it, it may be searched and read by future users. I personnaly like what I read, although I would have prefered to read it as an answer, but I get that it would take time write as a _good_ answer. Still good.

Comment: Understood, i'll leave it open.